# Verificacao de senha em tempo real com javascript e html

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite

Gostaria de uma ajuda de como seria uma verificação de senha em tempo real em javascript e html, penso em duas caixas de texto e uma mensagem abaixo que indicaria algo como "senha divergente" até os dois campos forem preenchidos com o mesmo valor, um ou exemplo me ajudaria muito!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Validade Senha</title>
    <script> function validarSenha(){
        senha1 = document.f1.senha1.value
        senha2 = document.f1.senha2.value
        if (senha1 == senha2) alert("SENHAS IGUAIS")
        else alert("SENHAS DIFERENTES") }
    </script>
    </head>
<body> VALIDAR SENHA <br> <br>
    <form action="" name="f1">
    Senha: <input type="password" name="senha1" size="20"> <br>
    Confirmar Senha: <input type="password" name="senha2" size="20"> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Validar" onClick="validarSenha()">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Obrigado por ler!

Comment: voce pode usar o patern e o campo required so que o patern no safari nao funciona ainda dai voce teria que usar tambem javascript

Comment: posta ai codigo html que eu disenrolo pra tu

Comment: Assanges me ajuda por favor!

Comment: cara a sua funcao validarSenha() esta correta so esta com algums erros de sintaxe mas voce quer o que a final exibir uma mensagem amigavel ao inves de um alert e isso? nao entende direito a sua pergunta ainda @Vitor Marques

Comment: O que eu queria é q não precisasse apertar o botao "Validar" para ele identificar se os dois campos estao iguais, esta verificacao estaria sendo feita a todo momento em tempo real.

Comment: vc pode tirar este alert, como um feedback poderia ser um texto no formulario mesmo, se vc me ajudar vai me ajudar bastante cara, gastei horas pra tentar fazer isto, sou leigo no assunto ainda...

Comment: mano acabou o cafe por aqui mas fica ai na espectativa concerteza alguem vai te ajudar abs

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar algo do tipo, não lembro muito bem como faz, porque tinha feito com jquery. Mas qualquer coisa se nao der eu edito aqui e coloca certinho. Blz? Também tem uns códigos prontos que voce encontra na internet que faz as verificaçoes bunitinho e tal. Espero contribuir em algo

```
  <input type="text" id="pass" onKeyPress="Verifica()"/>
<input type="text" id="pass2"  onKeyPress="Verifica()"/>
<script>
function Verifica(){
    val1=document.getElementById("pass").value;
    val2=document.getElementById("pass2").value;
    if(val1!=val2){
    document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#f00";
        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#f00";
    }
    else{document.getElementById("pass").style.borderColor="#000";
        document.getElementById("pass2").style.borderColor="#000";

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Legal! Está bem elementar, vou poder adaptar seu código facilmente, o feedback é a mudança de cor da borda né?

Comment: Assanges, esta função onKeypress, vc sabe se eu imputar um texto no textbox via codigo, sabe se ele vai identificar a mudanca?

Comment: Isso, acredito que nao identificaria, porque ele detecta o pressionamento de teclas, para alteraçao senao me engano é onChange=

Comment: LocalHost Infelizmente a funcao onChange e onKeypress exigem o pressionamento do teclado, se eu imprimir um texto na textbox o codigo nao percebe a mudanca e a funcao nao e executada