# Como é definido no banco de dados o campo confirmar senha

Tags: php, mysql

Ao se cadastrar no sistema o usuário terá que confirmar a senha para se cadastrar, porém não tenho conhecimento de como prosseguir e se isso é feito com alguma função em PHP ou alguma validação do tipo.Minha dúvida também é se eu preciso criar na minha tabela cadastro o campo confirmar senha.

Estou usando PHP e MYSQL para desenvolver este sistema de cadastros.

Comment: No caso eu crio uma tabela login e outra contendo o usuário ? E a função para verificar a senha faço com php ?

Comment: Você quer saber como ter no cadastro o campo confirmar senha, para o usuário nao digitar a senha errado sem querer?

Comment: Exato Guilherme

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não precisa fazer nada nobanco isso é apenas uma comparação no php:

```
if ($_POST["senha"] == $_POST["confirmar_senha"]) {
    //continua com o cadastro....
}
```

É legal fazer essa validação no front end também, assim o usuário não vai precisar recarregar a página para saber se apertou uma tecla erado, [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136644/verificacao-de-senha-em-tempo-real-com-javascript-e-html) tem um exeplo de como fazer com js

Comment: Muito obrigado, valeu pela dica.

Comment: Para que se dar o trabalho de tratar apenas no servidor? Isso não é bom para UX

Comment: Editei a resposta comentando isso e com um link exemplo